# JAVA Rest API and angular JS

Tags: java, angularjs, rest

I am trying to integrate java backend with front end  angular js ui.

I copied the ui code in `web-inf` folder and trying to show as on load of my dynamic project but I don't know how to serve static page in this web app.

Please help on it. Either I have to write something in `index.html` or `WEB.xml` file?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please read how to ask a question in SOF.

Comment: A more concise question about any particular issue will be appreciated.  refer: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: index.html is the landing page of the application that is served when you hit <server:port>/<applicationname>. so yes you should write something there just to understand if the page is coming up or not. Web.xml contains (apart from other configurations) the setting to mark "index.html" as default landing page.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is my 5 cents,

Angular js is UI Framework and it should be mounted in HttpServer (node js?)

Where as Java is backend and you need to expose it as Webservice and host in web server.

I think you are using REST to consume your service in UI.

Comment: yes i am  using REST to consume web service in UI.So how it will be wheather it will be seprate project for angular js ui mounted with node js npm.

Comment: Angular is mounted in node server and java in web server(eg: tomcat)